# При работе перепоняется vector: "vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, vector, динамические-массивы, stl

Около месяца изучаю C++, несколько дней пытаюсь отладить код. Ошибка, наверное, очевидная для бывалых, всё никак не находится. После ввода 1-го значения при работе программы происходит остановка и сообщение "vector subscript out of range". Подскажите, пожалуйста, где искать ошибку...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Инициализация кол-ва отрезков и вектора координат.
    int n;
    cin >> n;


    vector <double> v;

    // Формирование вектора "v" из всех координат в порядке ввода.
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {

        cin >> v[i];
    }

    // Формирование возрастающего вектора "w" из всех неравных координат.
    bool goo = true;
    vector <double> w;

    for (int j = 0; goo; j++) {
        double per = v[0]; // переменной присваивается 1-е значение вектора v
        goo = false; // условие завершения цикла при отсутствии нового элемента


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            double vi = v[i]; // для условия

            // инициализация 1-го элемента
            if (j == 0) {


                if (per > vi) {     
                    per = vi;
                }
                w[j] = per;
                goo = true;
            }

            // инициализация 1+ элементов
            else {
                int gop = j - 1; // для задания элемента вектора
                if (w[gop] < v[i]) {
                    if (per > v[i] || per < w[gop]) {
                        per = v[i];
                    }
                    w[j] = per;
                    goo = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Очень естественно, что вы не успели за месяц изучать материал  до такого уровня, чтобы понять как  пользоваться STL контейнерами...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы создаете вектор нулевой длины

```
vector <double> v;
```

После чего пытаетесь писать в него - куда?

```
// Формирование вектора "v" из всех координат в порядке ввода.
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {

    cin >> v[i];
}
```

Или указывайте в конструкторе количество элементов заранее

```
vector <double> v(2*n);
```

или пользуйтесь вектором как обычно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
    double d;
    cin >> d;
    v.push_back(d);
}
```

Естественно, что то же относится и к работе с вектором `w`, например...